# application managed transactions in J2EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, cdi

Does anyone have an example of the best way to begin, commit/rollback a transaction from within a CDI managed bean within a J2EE 6 container.?

I have run into a particular case where the annotated approach won't work for me (I'm calling the method from another method in the same class) and I need to set the transaction boundaries manually. I would like to know what I can do in my code that would replicate the behavior of the following annotation:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can write your interceptor for transaction management, then you can add this interceptor for your method. See [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_151_transactional_interceptors_using).

In Java EE 7 we have magical (:)) @Transactional annotation for declarative transaction management as well as in EJB.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for something a little more direct. I have found an example of injecting at UserTransaction into a CDI bean, but I couldn't find a way using that to emulate the behavior of TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW because that keeps the transaction information in a ThreadLocal and it would throw an exception if I already had an transaction in the local context.

Comment: FYI, I worked(hacked) around this by creating a new class with the @TransactionAttribute annotation. Since the new class was injected by CDI, the transaction was then handled by the container (which I prefer). I did find that the documentation available for this on the internet is sparse.

Comment: Did you annotate your class as @Stateless? The @TransactionAttribute annotation in JavaEE 6 works for EJB only.